# Having problem with diffusion model, are lowering the steps and num_timesteps related?

Tags: pytorch, indices

python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=3 --master_port=12233 --use_env run_train.py 
**--diff_steps 1000 **
--lr 0.0001 
**--learning_steps 3000 **
--save_interval 600 
--seed 102 
--noise_schedule sqrt 
--hidden_dim 128 
--bsz 2048 
--dataset qqp 
--data_dir datasets/ForTest 
--vocab bert 
--seq_len 128 
--schedule_sampler lossaware 
--notes test-qqp

I change the 'learning steps' and 'diff steps'.

File "/home/documents/DiffuSeq-main/diffuseq/gaussian_diffusion.py", line 805, in ddim_sample_loop_progressive
indices = list(range(self.num_timesteps))[::-1][::gap]
ValueError: slice step cannot be zero
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 2903262) of binary: /home/yjhongkr/miniconda3/envs/dec/bin/python
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.local_elastic_agent:[default] Worker group failed
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Worker group FAILED. 3/3 attempts left; will restart worker group
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Stopping worker group
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Rendezvous'ing worker group
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Rendezvous complete for workers. Result:

And some problems come up with 'slice step'. Would there be some relations between them?

gap is determined as '1'like this.

def ddim_sample_loop_progressive(
self,
model,
shape,
noise=None,
clip_denoised=True,
denoised_fn=None,
model_kwargs=None,
device=None,
progress=False,
eta=0.0,
langevin_fn=None,
mask=None,
x_start=None,
gap=1
):

I want to know whether it is related.

If it is, I have to run the model all over again...